# Is caching transactions and metric changes in RAM a good strategy for high-performance logging in Exodus database?

Tags: database, performance, kotlin, backend, metrics

I’m using JetBrain’s Exodus database. Right now I’m about to implement a transaction audit log with metrics collection. It’s assumed that a lot of transactions will be executed per second.

- How does Exodus perform if tasked to update / add a lot of entities to a persistent entity store?
- Are there optimizations you would suggest?
- Should I cache transactions/ metric changes in RAM and ‘submit’ them in a set interval?

I’m new the Exodus so I haven’t really tried much. Idk what the performance of Exodus might be and what the best practices in such a case are.